# redirect automatically my ajax and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to automaticaly redirect to a page and post to it on successful login,but i gets redirected but the data which i post do not arrives.plz suggest some answer thanks in advance

**Here is my ajax code:**

```
 $(document).ready(function (e){
        $("#loginform").on('submit',(function(e){  
        e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
        url: "checklogin.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {name:$('#loginname').val(),password:$('#loginpassword').val()},dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
        var status=data;
        var hii="sajal";
        if(hii==status){
        console.log("helllooo");
        post('http://localhost/DLFin/welcome.php', {name:"sajal"});
        }
        else{
        $("#loginerror h3").css("display", "block");
        }
        },
        error: function(){console.log("ERROR");$("#loginerror h3").css("display", "block");}            
        });
        }));
        });
```

**REdirected Page:**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
include 'config.php';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if (isset($_POST["name"])) {
        $name= $_POST["name"];

    if($name=="sajal")
    {
?>
<div class="logowelcome">
            <h1 align="middle"> ADMINISTRATOR </h1>
            </div>
<div class="centerwelcome">
<div class="menuleft">
<a class="menucontent" align="middle" href="http://localhost/DLFin/home.php">Home</a>
<a class="menucontent" align="middle" onclick="loadadd()"">Add</a>
<a class="menucontent" align="middle" onclick="loadedit()">Edit</a>
<a class="menucontent" align="middle" onclick="loadlist()">List</a>
</div>
<div id="ajaxdiv">
</div>
</div>
<?php
    }
  } 
}
?>
```

Comment: What dataType format checklogin.php will return? if anything just mention it in ajax

Comment: It will return a string

Comment: Tthe main problem is in   post('http://localhost/DLFin/welcome.php', {name:"sajal"}); this line the page got redirected but data get by redirected page is undefined

Comment: actually it $.post not post and it won't redirect it executed the welcome.php file and get the response to your original page....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to post some data to some page on server side, then instead of this:

```
post('http://localhost/DLFin/welcome.php', {name:"sajal"});
```

To pass the parameter with redirection you shouls use this code:

**============  By using `GET`   =================**

```
....
......
if(hii==status){
        console.log("helllooo");
        window.location.href = "http://localhost/DLFin/welcome.php?name=sajal";
}
.....
....
```

As you can see we are passing the parameter in the URL (`GET request`), so on the server side you will have to get the as shown below:

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
```

**============  By using `POST`   =================**

First, create a form with hidden filed on the page like:

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/DLFin/welcome.php" id="my_form">
    <input type="hidden" id="name" name="name">
</form>
```

Now on success, put the value in the hidden field and and submit the form,

```
....
......
if(hii==status){
        console.log("helllooo");
        //window.location.href = "http://localhost/DLFin/welcome.php?name=sajal";
        $('#name').val('sajal');
        $('#my_form').submit();
}
.....
....
```

Comment: BY this it is only posting data doesnt get redirected.

Comment: IT got redirected but i want to post and redirect simultaneously as to get validated by the redirected php page i am eding php file also

Comment: still not working Error:Undefined index: name in /var/www/DLFin/welcome.php on line 18

Comment: Put a `print_r($_REQUEST);` on `welcome.php` and seen what is in the array !

Comment: Still facing problems ??

Comment: it prints Undefined ,can you plz suggest answers related to post requests

Comment: Oops !! Sorry, it was my mistake ! Instead of `&` it should be `?` ! Edited my code, it should work now.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added the code for doing it with `POST`, well it should work but not confident. Let me know it that also works or not !